# Installing vendor program - libpython3.so: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shared-libraries

I'm getting an error at runtime when running a vendor program. I've been getting several dynamic lib errors, and have been walking through and solving each one. I am stuck on 'python3'

I am running CentOS 7.6.

The error I am getting is:

error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Usually I expect to search for the package, install it, and then add any paths as necessary.

1. I tried ldd, but the vendor file isn't a dynamic executable.
2. LD_LIBARY_PATH is set to /user/local/lib:/opt/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
3. If I run python3.6 -V, I get 'Python 3.6.7' which indicates python 3.* is installed.
4. I search from / for: python3*so and there are no libraries on my disk

Searches reveal specific python library versions, but not a generic python3, I'm missing something. How do I install and resolve the python3 library dependency?

Comment: The default CentOS 7.6 **Python3** is `python3-3.3.2`, currently `python3-3.3.2-12.el7.x86_64`, and the connected `python3-libs-3.3.2` provides **libpython3.so**. The version you have is a non-standard ? How was it installed ? If it was a package, you can do like `$ rpm -qa | grep -i python3` ... to get the package name.

Comment: I followed these instructions:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-4-on-centos-7/

When I run that command, there is no libpython3.so. I only have python36u*.

Comment: OK, `python36u-libs-3.6.7-1.ius.el7.x86_64` provides `/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0`. ... You can try making a symlink : `# cd /usr/lib64/ && ln -s libpython3.6m.so.1.0 libpython3.so` ... ... May work, or may not work with your program.

Comment: Worked. Is this an error with the vendor? I can mark as answer if you post it, or I can delete this.

Comment: Not an error with the vendor software. I.e. they created the program for CentOS 7, which have `libpython3.so` by default. About  "AdditionalResources"  https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories → "The ... warnings about updates and priorities should still be heeded."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. the "ius repo" : https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/python36u.html **and** https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/python36u-libs.html

`python36u-libs-3.6.7-1.ius.el7.x86_64` provides `/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0`

You can make a symlink, to create the missing `libpython3.so´

```
$ cd /usr/lib64/
# ln -s libpython3.6m.so.1.0 libpython3.so
```

See https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories for warnings about updates and priorities when you have installed packages from 3rd party repo´s.